# ruby - loop capybara click all elements

Tags: ruby, testing, automation, automated-tests, capybara

May you help me in this matter, pls?
I would like to be able to delete all my files, but I would like to use a loop structure. How could I do this using the foreach in ruby, using the capybara? I've tried several posts and I did not get the expected result.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XttS1.png)

Delete File

Comment: <button class="Button Button__Large File__Button">Delete File</button>

Comment: Show the code you’ve tried and explain what didn’t work - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there are no other buttons with the the class File__Button, you should be able to do something like:

```
page.all(:css, 'button.File__Button').each do |button_element|
    button_element.click
end
```

If there is a confirmation, you will need to click that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Oldie but still the first google hit. What I ended up using

```
all('button', text: 'Delete File').each(&:click)
```